# Simplifying a four term Boolean expression using Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have the following Boolean expression that I would like to simplify. I know that I could use a Karnaugh map to simplify, but I need to use Boolean  Algebra and simplify step by step.

$'$ is NOT

$+$ is OR
$$AB'C+A'BC+ABD+CD'+D'$$
I was able to only get his far.
$$AB'C+A'BC+ABD+D'$$

Looking on Wolfram Alpha, I see that this can be more simplified to the following, I'm unsure of what theorems to use to reduce this anymore.

$$AB+AC+BC+D'$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, I suppose you know that in Boolean algebras, $XY \leq X$, so that $X + XY = X$.
(This is what you used in that little bit you advanced.)
Now,
\begin{align}
ABC (ABD + D') 
&= ABCD + ABCD'\\
&= ABC(D+D') = ABC,
\end{align}
so that $ABC \leq ABD + D'$, whence $ABC + ABD + D' = ABD + D'$.
We also use the fact that $ABD' + D' = D'$.

Using this, we get
\begin{align}
AB'C + A'BC + ABD + CD' + D'
&= AB'C + A'BC + ABD + D'        \\
&= AB'C + A'BC + ABC + ABD + D'  \\
&= AB'C + A'BC + ABD + ABC + ABD' + D'\\
&= ABD + ABD' + ABC + AB'C + ABC + A'BC + D'\\
&= AB(D+D') + AC(B+B') + BC(A+A') + D'\\
&= AB + AC + BC + D'.
\end{align}